# What's the reason Android Reverse Tethering require root?

Tags: usb, tethering, wifi-tethering, reverse-tether, usb-tethering

From what i know:

1. Android Tethering, share internet from Android to laptop via USB cable works without root.
2. Android Reverse Tethering, share internet from laptop Ethernet to Android via USB cable [require root](http://www.howtogeek.com/214375/how-to-reverse-tether-an-android-smartphone-or-tablet-to-your-pc/).

So I'm curious what's the technical reason/limitation of Non-root Android Tethering is allow but not vice versa.

Comment: Normal *tethering* is implemented at a system level, ie. it's a system feature; it requires root on devices that don't implement it. *Reverse tethering* is no system feature and thus no implemented at all. Using commands at the root level allows you to tether even though it's not implemented in the system.

Comment: @GiantTree So why Reverse tethering is not system feature ?

Comment: Because manufacturers don't deem it necessary. You already have WiFi and mobile connection. No need for any USB connection.

Comment: Wonder if CM has this as a feature

Comment: Anyway, based on http://www.imore.com/usb-vs-bluetooth-vs-wi-fi-whats-best-way-tether-your-mac-your-iphone-or-ipad , USB tethering is the fastest and most reliable than WiFi.

Answer (score 1):

ReverseTethering does **not** require root. If your device runs ICS or newer.

A few months ago, I was wondering the very same thing and started to investigate. Eventually, I started to develop my own solution. The result is an app that works on devices running Android 4.0 or higher on client side, and all major desktop OSs on the host side.

The app is available on Google Play: [ReverseTethering NoRoot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.floriandraschbacher.reversetethering.free)